# Position Video so it will scale on mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have the following code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-sunset-pe8pgh?file=/src/styles.css

What I'm trying to achieve is to scale the video on mobile without losing any of the video element, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

i check your code. Please give width to video component, for example-

```
     <video
      className="razmi-video"
      autoPlay
      loop
      muted
      playsinline="true"
      disablePictureInPicture="true"
      width={100} <--- Width Here
    >
```

Hope you'll get your answer if you still facing issue lemme know, i will help you.
Thanks